# Is it possible for a project to change the Platform tools from the Intel c++ compiler to the v143 build tools In VS2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, icc

In VS2022，Is it possible for a project to change the Platform tools from the Intel c++ compiler  to the  v143 build tools  with no modification or modification as less as possible,
and build the project successfully?

In VS2019, I have tried to change the "Platform Toolset" setting directly, with no other changes to the project, but the compilation return with errors like : "byte" is ambiguous , element  has valid value“MaxSpeedHighLevel” from Microsoft.CppCommon.targets。 So Will the VS2022 have the same question or it has new feather to void these question?

Comment: Maybe. Big question - Is the project possibly using any compiler specific extensions?

Comment: The answer is a resounding **yes**!  We have done that on my project, which is over 50 million lines of code.  We do it about every 2-3 years, when upgrading compilers, or (relevant to your question) when we moved off of the Intel C++ compiler to VS2022.  As long as you've coded your project with that requirement in mind, you shouldn't have much problem.

Comment: Project > Properties > General > "Platform Toolset" setting.

Comment: In VS2019, I have tried to change the  "Platform Toolset" setting directly, with no other changes to the project, but the compilation return with errors like :  "byte" is ambiguous , element  <Optimization>  has  valid  value“MaxSpeedHighLevel” from Microsoft.CppCommon.targets。   So Will the VS2022 have the same question or it has new feather to void these question?

Comment: In VS2019, I have tried to change the "Platform Toolset" setting directly, with no other changes to the project, but the compilation return with errors like : "byte" is ambiguous , element <Optimization> has valid value“MaxSpeedHighLevel” from Microsoft.CppCommon.targets。 So Will the VS2022 have the same question or it has new feather to void these question?  @Eljay

Comment: Thanks @Bop for your reply.  I add new info for this problem,  hope the new hint from you

Comment: I would expect VS2022 to have the same issues.  And probably a few more.  All of which should be tractable, by addressing the issues in the code and fixing them.

Comment: Can you provide  a minimal reproducible example? The problem is caused by namespace.
Avoid `using namespace std`.